# automatic scroll animation disables user scrolling - ability to override it

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, overriding

i want to make a website that is scrolled very very slowly to the bottom all the time.

```
var docEnd= $(document).height();
$('html,body').stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop:docEnd}, 1200000,'linear');
```

the problem is that it is disables user scrolling.
and the scroll event lisetener do not distinguish between the animation and the user scrolling.

i need to make the user be able to override it:
web is auto scroll to bottom --> the user will scroll --> the animation stops and the user scrolls wherever he wnats -->  when he finishes the 
animation returns.

thanks a lot in advance !
Rotem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc=$('html,body');
var docEnd= doc.height();

doc.animate({scrollTop:docEnd}, 120000,'linear');

$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    console.log("scrolling");
    doc.clearQueue();
    doc.stop();
} ) );

$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    console.log("done");
    doc.animate({scrollTop:docEnd}, 120000,'linear');
} ) );
```

here is the [demo for the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/shaNx/LLoLnob1/)

It uses [debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js) plugin for checking if scrolling or not. While scrolling clear the queue and stops the autoscroll

Comment: ok thank you so !  but for some reason the speed of the auto scroll seem to be slower than it suppose to be, also when i try to reduce the value of "1200000" to a smaller value, the animation seem to become not smooth and become fragmented.

seems to be connected to the row below...btw what the "250" does ?
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){

Comment: 250 millisecond is the delay inbetween, try reducing that delay for smooth scrolling but it may take up more memory